Spark Parquet - Write to Single file
I am fetching data from the Database and using ResultSet i am creating
org.apache.spark.sql.Row (required to dump in the parquet file using Spark Sql)
Since the number of records in the database are large i am doing this in batches of 2L.
I have used coalesce(1) to make sure it has 1 partition and writes only to single file.
But what i am getting is multiple parquet files in batches of 2L.(though partition is only 1)
I need only single parquet file as if i have multiple my read performance is slow as it is creating multiple small files of 2000kb each.
But combined file size is less than 100Mb.
I tried this at the end to combine it into single file but this may reduce my write performance:
//Read the batch file and write it back to a single file
Dataset<Row> batchDf = spark.read().parquet(parquetFileName);
batchDf.repartition(1).write().mode("overwrite").parquet(parquetFileName);       

Original Code:
    while (rs.next()) {
            Object[] fieldValues = new Object[columnCount];
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                Object val = rs.getObject(i);
                if(val != null){
                    fieldValues[i - 1] = val;
                }  
            }
            rows.add(RowFactory.create(fieldValues));

            // Write the batch to Parquet when it reaches the specified batch size
            if (rows.size() >= batchSize) {

                // Create DataFrame from the current batch of rows
                Dataset<Row> batchDf = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);

                // Write the batch to Parquet
                batchDf.coalesce(1).write().mode("append").parquet(parquetFileName);
                doesDataExist = true;

                // Clear the batch for the next set of rows
                rows.clear();
            }
        }

        // Write any remaining rows (less than batch size) to Parquet
        if (!rows.isEmpty()) {

            Dataset<Row> remainingDf = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema);
            remainingDf.coalesce(1).write().mode("append").parquet(parquetFileName);
            doesDataExist = true;
        }



You are appending. Each loop will add a single file. 10 loops will give you 10 files.  Do you actually need to loop like this?

Hi @Andrew If i don't do in loop it is giving me OOM as the org.apache.spark.sql.Row is consuming large amount of memory.
So doing in batches and dumping in the file.
